# GCC fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, stdio

I'm trying to compile a program in C on OS X 10.9 with GCC 4.9 (experimental). For some reason, I'm getting the following error at compile time:

```
gcc: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

I then tried a simple Hello World program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Again, upon running `gcc -o ~/hello ~/hello.c`, I got the same error. I'm using an experimental version of `gcc`, but it seems implausible that there would be a release which generated errors upon importing `stdio`. What could be causing this issue, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: You can see where gcc is looking for header files by doing `echo "#include <bogus.h>" | gcc -v -x c -` and examining the search paths.

Comment: Very useful command! It doesn't look like `stdio.h` is in any of GCC's search paths.

Comment: Mavericks no longer has a base /usr/include. You need to link it into place from the XCode OS 10.9 SDK.

Comment: BTW, `int main`'s first parameter is an int and not int *argc.

Comment: @YannRamin Thanks, going to try that.

Comment: @flippex17 Really? I thought it was *arg*ument *c*ount, and then the *arg*ument *v*alues.

Comment: Yes, it's an `integer` type.

Comment: @user2615799: It is argument count. It's not pointer to argument count.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. @YannRamin I'm not sure how to do that, actually. I'm currently at Xcode > Preferences > Locations, but I can't find any options for library locations. Couldn't this be done by setting the `$LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: No, since headers are not libraries. `C_INCLUDE_PATH` or the `-isystem` flag are what you want.

Comment: I tried setting `C_INCLUDE_PATH` (previously an empty variable) to the location of `stdio.h`, but the issue persists. On a possibly related note, I get no issues when I try importing `stdio.h` in `gdb`.

Comment: @user2615799 Its at `sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include /usr/include`

Comment: @YannRamin Location changed, but when I fix that I get `ln: /usr/include: Operation not permitted`.  Running as *sudo*!

Answer (score 208, accepted):

#### macOS

I had this problem too (encountered through Macports compilers). Previous versions of Xcode would let you install command line tools through xcode/Preferences, but xcode5 doesn't give a command line tools option in the GUI, that so I assumed it was automatically included now. Try running this command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

If you see an error message that developer tools are already installed (and still header files can't be found), wipe out any existing one to do a fresh installation:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

#### Ubuntu

*(as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29284967/1287376))*

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

#### Alpine Linux

*(as per this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580758/gcc-fatal-error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory#comment70998172_29284967))*

```
apk add libc-dev
```

Comment: If you're using Xcode 6 beta 5, this command might fail. In that case you need to do `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`. When you're done, switch back using `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app`.

Comment: Wow. Still working with Xcode 8.0 and Sierra in 2017.

Comment: Alpine guide is extremely usefull for Docker images based on alpine distro, works as wanted

Comment: any suggestion for windows users? I am having this problem on windows

Comment: For macOS users who're still having problems after  installing CLTs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342521/clang-on-macos-having-problems-with-its-includes/

Comment: In some situations, you may need to run `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` to wipe out any existing installations before running `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: For those who still have problems after wiping out the existing one and doing a fresh installation, what got rid of the error for me was to run the following on my mac brew reinstall gcc

Answer (score 47):

## Mac OS Mojave

The accepted answer no longer works. When running the command `xcode-select --install` it tells you to use "Software Update" to install updates.

In this [link](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/338#issuecomment-426777849) is the updated method:

Open a Terminal and then:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

This will open an installation Wizard.

### Update 12/2019

After updating to Mojave 10.15.1 it seems that using `xcode-select --install` works as intended.

Comment: Reinstalling the headers works also when upgrading to Xcode 10.2.

Comment: When I open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg, I get a scary Warning from the Installer: "This package is incompatible with this version of macOS and may fail to install."  I have Mojave.

Comment: @SteveSiegel what Mac OS version are you running? I upgraded to 10.15.1 and I no longer had to do this workaround. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: "updating to Mojave 10.15.1" that's incorrect. @SteveSiegel The pkg is deprecated. SDKROOT should be used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63343829/10063119

Answer (score 31):

On Ubuntu:

```bash
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

specially ruby developers that have problem installing `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` on their VMs

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. This lib also solves some other issues. Recently, I encountered it trying to run a benchmark for petabyet.com (which uses gcc).

Comment: On alpine linux I needed `apk add libc-dev`

Comment: This is not working for me on ubuntu.  I already have libc6-dev installed and it is still looking in the wrong location for the file.

Answer (score 4):

I know my case is rare, but I'll still add it here for someone who troubleshoots it later.
I had a Linux Kernel module target in my Makefile and I tried to compile my user space program together with the kernel module that doesn't have stdio.
Making it a separate target solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I installed "XCode: development tools" from the app store and it fixed the problem for me.

I think this link will help: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12&ls=1

Credit to Yann Ramin for his advice. I think there is a better solution with links, but this was easy and fast.

Good luck!

Comment: Are you referring to just normal Xcode? Or is there some special version called "XCode: development tools"? Because I only see normal Xcode in the App Store. Granted, this is 4 years into the future from when this answer was posted.