# Fatal error: #include <stdio.h> generated after "pip install mysql-python" command

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, anaconda

Like many people, I am having issues getting mysql and python to work together. My specs are:

OSX10.9.2
Anaconda 1.9.1 with python 2.7.2, although 2.5 and 2.6 appear to be included
MySQL 5.6.16

I have written a python script where I try to import MySQLdb, or PyMySQL then MySQLdb, neither works.

I read many of the threads on stack overflow, and as a result I eventually tried

```
$ export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
$ export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
$ pip install mysql-python
```

The results are below. A fatal error was issued, as can be seen at the bottom of the output.

Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/lx/h7jq_qx92_j0n7plsjmr6wl40000gp/T/pip_build_vincent/mysql-python/setup.py) egg_info for package mysql-python

Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D_*version*_=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Users/vincentlaufer/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
    In file included from _mysql.c:29:
    /Users/vincent/anaconda/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
    #include 
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/vincentlaufer/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/lx/h7jq_qx92_j0n7plsjmr6wl40000gp/T/pip_build_vincent/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/lx/h7jq_qx92_j0n7plsjmr6wl40000gp/T/pip-6aqGYj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7

/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D_*version*_=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Users/vincent/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64

In file included from _mysql.c:29:
/Users/vincent/anaconda/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

## include stdio.h

```
     ^
```

1 error generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

---

Cleaning up...
Command /Users/vincent/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/lx/h7jq_qx92_j0n7plsjmr6wl40000gp/T/pip_build_vincent/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/lx/h7jq_qx92_j0n7plsjmr6wl40000gp/T/pip-6aqGYj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lx/h7jq_qx92_j0n7plsjmr6wl40000gp/T/pip_build_vincent/mysql-python
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/vincentlaufer/.pip/pip.log

I would like to thank everyone for the many answers provided that got me this far already, but also to ask if anyone knows how to solve this issue. Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inclusion of the line:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

solves this problem, as per: [GCC fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580758/gcc-fatal-error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)