# Lxml installation error for Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

Trying to install lxml on mac osx yosemite for python 2.7.10

Using command pip install lxml, I receive:     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
    #include 
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Complete error: Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/h2/hwn1y9sd54b6tl2wyb6vc_kh0000gp/T/pip-build-St5xbb/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/h2/hwn1y9sd54b6tl2wyb6vc_kh0000gp/T/pip-8QC6OG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/h2/hwn1y9sd54b6tl2wyb6vc_kh0000gp/T/pip-build-St5xbb/lxml

I have searched and cannot find a solution.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have xcode installed try the following

```
  $xcode-select --install
```

You could also try installing python via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
  $brew install python
```

See these links that are related to you problem.

[Fatal error: #include <stdio.h> generated after "pip install mysql-python" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603195/fatal-error-include-stdio-h-generated-after-pip-install-mysql-python-comma)

[GCC fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580758/gcc-fatal-error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: I already have python installed and I would prefer not to use xcode.

Comment: How did you install it?
I do believe the problem is related to missing libraries that can be installed by the above xocde-select command.

Comment: Ok, I installed python using homebrew (your same command), and then ran pip install lxml again.  The terminal is hanging up and the top bar is switching between "xcrun" and "lipo"

Comment: I found that resolving my xcrun/lipo bounce as described in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667916/xcrun-lipo-freezes-with-os-x-mavericks-and-xcode-4-x was able to resolve that problem, and after this my lxml installation was successful.  I suppose this was more of a build issue than an (incorrectly tagged) python issue :)  thank you!