# How to install codeblocks in Linux mint 17.1 (KDE)

Tags: c++, c, linux, codeblocks

I have already installed codeblocks in my linux mint 17.1 (KDE), using this command line

> sudo apt-get install codeblocks

, but when i tried to compile and run a c program on codeblocks it shows me this error

> /home/redwan/Programmin/C Program/hello.c|1|fatal error: stdio.h: No
>   such file or directory| ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>   (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Please someone help me to run c as well as c++ programs properly in linux mint 17.1(KDE) using codeblocks.

And Sorry for my bad english .

Comment: install compiler first ... **sudo apt-get install gcc**

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580758/gcc-fatal-error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save this into a file named 'install.sh' (without quotes) in your home directory, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and run the command 'bash install.sh' (again without quotes).

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
sudo apt-get install codeblocks -y
sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean -y

exit 0;
```

Comment: You can combine the three installations into a single step, `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential codeblocks codeblocks-contrib`. Also, running `update` before and after is not necessary. If you want to use an actual update, use `dist-upgrade` which can additionally change dependencies as needed.

Comment: I would be curious if anyone can get codeblocks to install on Linux Mint 17.3, but have given up trying to install codeblocks.
After attempting to install the packages, I could not get past codeblocks needing package libwxgtk3.0-0v5, and could not get libwxgtk3.0-0v5 to install after downloadng the package.