# Linux Mint Codeblocks Doesn't Work When I Compile

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

When I try to do my basic hello world and compile it, but the debug spits this out

```
-------------- Build: Debug in hello world (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c "/home/a/Desktop/le programa¢iao épica/programas/hello world/main.cpp" -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o "bin/Debug/hello world" obj/Debug/main.o   
g++: error: obj/Debug/main.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I've tried uninstalling then rebooting then reinstalling, but nothing... Is there anything I can do on Linux Mint or should I look for another IDE. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Hard to tell if you even have a compiler installed.

Comment: Create a brand new "hello world" project. Build it, and [edit] your question to show the full and complete output from the very first build of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've found this post with the same problem as me I used the soulution with 6 upvotes and noting so I guess It doesn't have to do with me having a compiler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865321/how-to-install-codeblocks-in-linux-mint-17-1-kde?rq=1 (also I'll edit the the post to show the full contents of Build Log).

Comment: avoid paths containing spaces or non-ascii characters

Comment: The author of the post you linked to doesn't have "the same problem", for them there's a headerfile missing; in your error message the compiler complains about a missing .obj, which, given its location, should be something you previously built or about the fact that it can't find the directory where to generate said object.

Comment: I think you're right, though when creating the project I just did so with a console project and keeping all the files to the "le programa¢iao épica" folder. I also just now created a new C++ project to see what it outputs when compiling and it's the same message. I'm pretty noobish in the programming and linux so perhaps I made a dumb mistake. Have any ideas what it could mean? Anyways thanks for your time.