# fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a problem with `#include <stdio.h>` on mac Mojave 10.14.1

I have a default gcc compiler together with other gcc compilers.

```
DorothyeMacBook:Desktop dorothy$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

The version is

```
DorothyeMacBook:Desktop dorothy$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/7.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Configured with: ../gcc-7.1.0/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.1.0 (GCC)
```

Now I am in the path :
/Users/dorothy/Desktop

I have stdio.h in the lib

```
DorothyeMacBook:Desktop dorothy$ find /usr -name "stdio.h"
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/7.1.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0/8.2.0/include/ssp/stdio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0/8.2.0/include-fixed/stdio.h
```

However when I compile the file under the current path /Users/dorothy/Desktop    Terminal will give me an error:

```
DorothyeMacBook:Desktop dorothy$ gcc  inverse.c -o inv
inverse.c:1:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Seems kind of strange that `gcc` was built only for c++ and fortran but you are trying to use it as a `c` compiler.  If you rename `inverse.c` to `inverse.cpp` does it work?

Comment: `Configured with: ../gcc-7.1.0/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran` Yeah this looks odd, mine has `c` in this list, and without it  I can't tell if `stdio.h` would be supported. Judging from the error message I'd say it is not.

Comment: Did you install xcode?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Why do you think this us a duplicate? There are many ways software installations can be messed up. The issue there appeared to have been a broken Xcode/Apple tools installation. This question seems to involve some GCC version, which is different (Apple uses Clang now).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Because the symptoms are the same — upgraded to Mojave and …  No `stdio.h` was how I encountered the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The question does not indicate there was an upgrade to Mojave from a previous macOS version, just that 10.14.1 is the version the issue is occurring on. And a comment has identified a likely cause: The GCC installation was configured for C++ and FORTRAN and hence does not support C.

Comment: See [Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave) for a probable solution to your problem.  Not everyone agrees that your trouble will be resolved by the steps there, though I strongly suspect that what you're seeing is what I saw, and what the OP of that question saw — the system headers have been removed from `/usr/include` by Apple during an upgrade to Mojave.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Hi, according to your tip, I  jumped to the "Can't compile C program on a Mac after upgrade to Mojave ". Then I tried to install the package (macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: However, terminal gives me this error:Error: macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg: undefined method `xar!' for Formulary::FormulaNamespace03a5542d706800cf492f2f8aead0a0ff:Module

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Could you give me more advice and I was checking the release notes from Apple but not big help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCC fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580758/gcc-fatal-error-stdio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have a problem linking `gcc` with `stdio.h` on my mac. However, I have found an alternative way to compile the program with `gcc`.  I typed `brew install gcc` in my terminal, that means a new *gcc8.0.2* will be installed.(which is my case, I don't know what *gcc* you will get)  Then I use `gcc-8` instead of `gcc` to compile my program. In this way, the new *gcc8.0.2* is invoked.

You can check the command name for gcc variants by going to `/usr/local/bin`    All the names for `gcc` commands are listed there. As for me, those are

```
g++                 
g++-8               
gcc                 
gcc-8
```

If you have further question, you can contact me and I will give more details.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan Leffler is right. Apple made another big cake for us.
Since /usr/include has been moved (now it in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include after you install commandline tools), old versions of gcc build **cannot find the most bottom level include files**. And **this** is a problem. (What are there in their head) So only you are developer you use /usr/include?

This is **NOT** Unix-like.

Here is what happened. For gcc-4.9(gcc-4.9 and gcc-9 below are all brew gcc.), the include search paths are:

```
enter ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
.
/usr/local/include
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9/4.9.4_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0/4.9.4/include
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9/4.9.4_1/include
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9/4.9.4_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0/4.9.4/include-fixed
/System/Library/Frameworks
/Library/Frameworks
End of search list. here
```

There is system level file stdio.h, this is why stdio.h cannot be found.

The problem in:

```
inverse.c:1:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**is**:

Refer to /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9/4.9.4_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0/4.9.4/include/ssp/stdio.h

```
#ifndef _SSP_STDIO_H
#define _SSP_STDIO_H 1

#include <ssp.h>
#include_next <stdio.h>
```

#include_next means include next one name stdio.h, this one is just a guider.

Give a deprecated shot. cp all files in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include to /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9/4.9.4_1/lib/gcc/4.9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0/4.9.4/include-fixed, gcc-4.9 will work again.

But for gcc-9 the path problem is fine. See:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
.
/usr/local/include
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include # key path
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.1.0/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.1.0/include
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.1.0/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.1.0/include-fixed
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
```

Actually this bug can be simply fixed by reinstall xcode commandline tools, after that gcc-4.9 will work again.