# Clang on MacOS having problems with its includes

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdk, clang

I have built from scratch Clang on MacOS and I am having problems with it.

Used following to configure Clang for building:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/clang-12 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="AArch64;ARM;X86" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;libcxx;libcxxabi;lldb" ../llvm
```

This is my test program:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
return 0;
}
```

1. OK if compiled with Clang 11.0.3 that ships with XCode `clang++ -c test.cc`
2. ERROR if using new Clang 12 (built)  `/opt/clang-12/bin/clang++ -c test.cc`

```
In file included from test.cc:2:
In file included from /opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:138:
In file included from /opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:214:
In file included from /opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95:
/opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Depending on what I am trying to include I get different include errors.

```
➜ tests /opt/clang-12/bin/clang++ -v -c test.cc
clang version 12.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git b529c5270c99e0ca18e3cbd9a5f50eb0970e560a)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/clang-12/bin
 (in-process)
 "/opt/clang-12/bin/clang-12" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.15.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Werror=undef-prefix -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test.cc -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-rounding-math -munwind-tables -fcompatibility-qualified-id-block-type-checking -target-cpu penryn -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 556.6 -v -resource-dir /opt/clang-12/lib/clang/12.0.0 -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /opt/clang-12/lib/clang/12.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/duddie/Projects/Audio/1voct/1voct_modular/tests -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcolor-diagnostics -o test.o -x c++ test.cc
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 based upon LLVM 12.0.0git default target x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /opt/clang-12/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
In file included from test.cc:2:
In file included from /opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:138:
In file included from /opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:214:
In file included from /opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95:
/opt/clang-12/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

3. ERROR if Clang 11.0.3 (XCode) or Clang 12 but target for ARM `clang++ -target arm-none-eabi -c test.cc`

```
test.cc:2:10: fatal error: 'ostream' file not found
#include <ostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following to the shell profile file `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zsh_profile` or any other way to set environment variable accessible to the shell you're running it in.

```
export SDKROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk"
```

Verify the correct path to the SDK on your macOS/Xcode version.

Reopen Terminal (sourcing the file may not work reliably).
Then try your compile command again.

```
/opt/clang-12/bin/clang++ -c test.cc
```

> The Command Line Tools package installs the macOS system headers
> inside the macOS SDK. Software that compiles with the installed tools
> will search for headers within the macOS SDK provided by either Xcode
> at:
> `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk`
> or the Command Line Tools at:
> `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk` depending on which
> is selected using xcode-select. The command line tools will search the
> SDK for system headers by default. However, some software may fail to
> build correctly against the SDK and require macOS headers to be
> installed in the base system under /usr/include. If you are the
> maintainer of such software, we encourage you to update your project
> to work with the SDK or file a bug report for issues that are
> preventing you from doing so. As a workaround, an extra package is
> provided which will install the headers to the base system. In a
> future release, this package will no longer be provided. You can find
> this package at:
> `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-10-release-notes

Comment: While it helped compilation for macOS target, or should I say native x86_64, it still did not resolve anything for arm-none-eabi - which is my primary reason to compile own Clang.

Comment: Actually found out that -target arm-none-eabi caused that. -arch arm7 works

Answer (score 7):

Probably a more portable one (I found the hint at [llvm-project/llvm/utils/lit/lit/util.py:399](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/utils/lit/lit/util.py#L399)):

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx)
```

Also, you can also add `-isysroot` argument to clang driver to alter the default system root for header searching:

```
clang++ a.cpp -isysroot $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx)
```

More details and investigation notes [here](https://blog.nuullll.com/2021/05/15/building-llvm-project-with-ninja-on-macos.html)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I was able to fix the problem with MacOs Big Sur by doing

```
export SDKROOT='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk'
```