# go build error when i try to run a particular project

Tags: go, build

when i try to run a go project using go run main.go
i got error like this

```
 runtime/cgo
 _cgo_export.c:3:10: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 3 | #include <stdlib.h>`your text`
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
 compilation terminated.
```

also checked gcc

```
:~$ sudo apt install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file 'brave-browser-release.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
rahul@rahul-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK:~$ ^C
```

when i try simple project is run without these error

Comment: You probably need `libc6-dev`as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20150282).